# Index a Relatively Positioned Range

Tags: google-sheets

I use a spreadsheet for balancing my finance accounts which looks a little like this:

```
A       | B                  | C             | D           | E
Account | Transaction Amount | Account Total | Description | Date
```

Transactions are in reverse-order by date so that I can see the newest balance first.

Because transactions for any account aren't in a fixed-position from each other I use this formula to sum a total:

```
=(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1)) + 
  INDEX(A3:E, MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 1)), A3:A, 0), 3)
 )
```

Where `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1))` is the transaction amount, and `INDEX(A3:E, MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 1)), A3:A, 0), 3)` is the last account total for the key in the A-field.

My problem is that when I shift cells a few of them will not start the search from the row below it (`A3`...) but add one (`A4`).

I would like to have a function like ADDRESS where I can refer to the cell-range starting right below the row the formula is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADDRESS is able to return a "cell-range starting right below the row the formula is in"

Adding the following formula to cell H7

```
=ADDRESS(ROW()+1,1)
```

The result is `$A$8`

Comment: Thank you, the function I ended up using did include ADDRESS: `INDEX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 2)&":A", 4)`.